# Pass Variable from Struct to Class in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, class, struct, swiftui

i Have a Structure and have some variable in it

```
struct Home: View {
    
    var token: String
    var loginapiurl: String
    var companyname: String
    
    @StateObject var dataservice = StatAPI()
```

i have to pass this **token** and **loginapiurl** in the **class**

```
class StatAPI: ObservableObject {


    @Published var statsdetails = [Result]()
    
    
    init()
    {
        
        print("in init")
        
        
        let currenDate = getCurrentDate()
        let past7DaysBeforeDate = past7dayDate(date1: currenDate)
        
        
        getStats(dateFrom: past7DaysBeforeDate, dateTo: currenDate)
    }
```

i want to use that two variable in init and passed in to getStats function

I am new to Swiftui. Can anyone help me about this

Comment: A view should not pass anything except user input to its model object. Where does your view get the values of `token` and `loginapiurl`?

Comment: i got it from previous page.. i.e login after successfully login it send these two variable from it using navigation link and pass it from there

Comment: I'd say that neither token nor loginapiurl relates to Home as a view, so the StatAPI should be created somewhere outside and injected here already prepared. That would be correct from flow design perspective.

Comment: @Asperi can you write a prototype here so i can relate as i am new in swiftui